# EF exception after upgrade to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have this asp.net core project (targeting standard framework) which I used to work on with VS 2015. I'd recently migrated the project to VS2017 and everything was going just fine until I needed a change in the db and as I ran the `add-migration` command I got this exception:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s):

+     $domain.SetData('project', $project)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException
```

I've seen people making all sort of suggestions here on SO like running VS as admin or upgrading EF libraries. those solutions did not work for me. 
Also there's only one project in the solution so the default project in package manager console can't be wrong.

Comment: As far as I can see, the new csproj format doesn't properly work with EF6.1.3... I think you need to keep the old project files for now (don't ask me for details, not using VS2017) https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/230